# Xcode Subversion (SCM) Difference between Refresh and Update

Tags: xcode, svn, refresh

I have configured Xcode to use Subversion (hosted on a remote webserver - Beanstalk.com).
In Xcode menu under SCM, I want to know the difference between two options

1. "Refresh Entire Project ..." and

2. "Update Entire Project ..."

Please help.

Thanks

Dev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the SCM Results window from the SCM menu item, click on the little 'text' button on the left-hand-side (might be at the bottom of the window to start with?), expand it so you can see a little more, and then run refresh and update to see what commands Xcode passes to SVN.

Sorry, can't speak for SVN right now, but for CVS it did this for me:

[image: Xcode SCM commands]

Answer (score 1):

I believe Refresh will check the repository if there is a newer, updated version of any files within your project that may have been committed by another developer since your last checkout.

Opening your SCM Results view will show you in the 'Update' column what files have been updated since your last checkout with an 'M'.

If you select Update, you will actually pull down those files and update your current project while Refresh will just check the files and list them in the SCM results window without downloading and overwriting your file.