# Update of SVN doesn't work

Tags: xcode, svn

I have a problem with my svn (hosted on Dreamhost) and my local version. I clicked on "Update button" and Xcode shows me the differences beetwen the local and remote version, with one conflict. I resolved it and the update button became active but if I press it, Xcode doesn't do anything.

Why? :(

Comment: What `svn` *commands* are you really doing? They work best in a plain terminal. And when you resolved a conflict, you should tell `svn` and commit your changes....

Comment: I just use the graphic client of Xcode :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SO answer "[Xcode Subversion (SCM) Difference between Refresh and Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792042/xcode-subversion-scm-difference-between-refresh-and-update)" should show you how to see what svn command is done behind an XCode "Update".

I suspect that the update has been completed, and any further "Update" will find the local workspace in sync with the remote SVN repo, hence:

- the active "Update" button (there are no more conflict to solve)
- the absence of result once "Update" is pressed (the local workspace is updated, and the remote SVN repo has no further changes to send to said local workspace).